# Python. VK. Авторизация

Tags: python, вконтакте

Пытаюсь авторизоваться ВК как пользователь (не как сообщество). Пробовал с помощью библиотеки vk_api:

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(login, password)
vk_session.auth()
```

выдаёт ошибку:
vk_api.exceptions.AuthError: Unknown error. Please send bugreport to vk_api@python273.pw

Хотя раньше работало. Вроде как этот метод авторизации устарел. Дальше пробовал авторизоваться с помощью requests - не работало и спомощью библиотеки VK - тоже не получилось. Может кто знает актуальный способ авторизации ВК?

Answer (score 0):

Для авторизации ВК всё же необходим `access_token`:

```
import vk

session = vk.Session(access_tokenMy)
api = vk.API(session)
print(api.users.get(v=5.92, user_id=1))
```

Этот код получает данные с аккаунта, чей `user_id` указан. Без указания `user_id` показывается информация того, чей `access_token` указан